# For notifications like a mailbox, what design pattern, how do I model my schema objects

Tags: email, design-patterns, database-design, observablecollection

In a webapp (ASP MVC), I have a view/page that lists new notifications/incoming messages similar to a list box (picture a mail box, but much simpler) across sessions for users. *I understand INotifyPropertyChange and Observables*

My scenario: I have a simple `Transactions table` with a `TransactionType`, only some transactions with `Transaction.Transactype == Approve/Reject` need notifications.

How do I model this in the database and the object so that I can pick up these changes, **everytime the user logs back in**, across session?

Here is what I did,

1. I created a separate  `Transaction.ApproveTable` and I attached a trigger on insert, but I am looking them across the sessions
2. I created an MSMQ journal, but its blocking since its serial from notifying other users. I also have a role notification scenario, where I notify all member of the role.

Comment: do your transaction have timestamps? can you guarantee that if you kepts a userrecord with a timestamp which transactions you processed thus far then you can determine which ones you need to do?

Comment: @Batavia yes I have timestamps, but in the database. Those only show when it was recorded for audits. Now, I if I create a new column, then it starts hitting my transactions table heavily. with 80 users, I am concerned on the load, do you think it will be a problem or DB to handle 80 users on win 2k12

Comment: you could create a user table with a last updated column (the timestamp). every time you notified a user of a transaction you update this user table. that way your database load should be minimal